# Regex for at least 8 + upper and lower+numbers or other non-alphabetic

Tags: regex

1. Contains at least 8 characters.
2. Contains upper and lower case letters.
3. Contains numbers or other non-alphabetic characters.

What could be the reg ex for the above criteria?

I am creating a check for stronger password :)

c# i am using

Comment: Do you have to use Regex for this? I have nothing against it, but for criteria 1 it might be easier to use a string length function instead. What language is this in?

Comment: This is no answer to your question, but I would like to recommend some reading on why forcing users to have the kind of password you are checking for is a bad practise: http://www.baekdal.com/tips/password-security-usability

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx expression to validate the input string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124796/regex-expression-to-validate-the-input-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z]).{8,}
```

See here: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/i26nwsTcaU)

Explained:

```
(?=.*?[a-z]) //lookahead, there has to be a lower case alphabetic char
(?=.*?[A-Z]) //lookahead, there has to be a upper case alphabetic char
(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z]) //lookahead, there has to be a non-alphabetic char
.{8,} // any character at least 8 times
```

Comment: which set of elements does specify special charterers here?

Comment: the [^a-zA-Z] means anything but alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 12):

Don't try to use one regexp for all rules -- it's hard, and more importantly it will be hard to read and modify by future programmers. Instead, write one function for each rule. Use a string length function for the first rule, then use separate regular expressions (or a simple scan of the string)for uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers.

Your test then becomes something like:

```
if (len(password) >= 8 &&
    contains_lower(password) &&
    contains_upper(password) &&
    contains_number(password)) {
    ...
}
```

Your code becomes absolutely clear in its intent, and if you have to change just one piece of the algorithm you don't have to reinvent a complex regular expression. Plus, you'll be able to unit test each rule independently.

Compare that to an example someone wrote in another answer to this question:

```
(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z]).{8,}
```

Which of these two answers looks easier to understand, easier to modify and easier to test? You can't even guess what the regex is doing until you spend a few (or many) moments studying it. And what if the requirement changes to ".. and has at least one underscore"? How do you change the pattern, especially when *you* weren't the one who came up with the pattern to begin with?

Comment: +1 fantastic - i dont know why i didnt think of this before 10000000x clearer!

Comment: Another important reason for not using regexes is they make it impossible to tell the user which part of your requirements his password doesn't fulfill