# Regex for upper and lower+numbers or other non-alphabetic

Tags: javascript, regex

See my post here

[Regex for at least 8 + upper and lower+numbers or other non-alphabetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029193/regex-for-at-least-8-upper-and-lowernumbers-or-other-non-alphabetic)

Suppose i just need this 2 condition below,
what should be the regular expression?

1. Contains upper and lower case letters.
2. Contains numbers or other non-alphabetic characters.

I tried `^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z])$`
but not working

<strike>BUT just-
 -`(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z])` is working</strike>

can i use just `(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z])` for the purpose?

Comment: Is this for legacy 7-bit ASCII, or is it for Unicode? The web is mostly Unicode now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the look ahead/behind are zero-width, "non-consuming". That means your

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z])$
```

will never match because the lookarounds consumed nothing and whats then left? only `^$` that would match an empty string, but this does not meet your lookahead criterias.

So you should use

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z]).*$
```

that `.*` will consume everything and the look aheads ensure the criterias.

you can also define a length replacing the `*` with `{x,}` where x is the minimum amount of characters of the string

Comment: @tchrist, and I thought I will get your upvote, because I explained so well why is expression is not working ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z])$
```

this means: start of string followed by anything containing lowercase or uppercase or non-alphabetic, but the next position must be end of string - this can not happen.

Your accepted aswer in your previous question is OK, is there any problem?
Here you can read something more about assertions in regex http://cz.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: This is for 7-bit data only, but the web is now mostly Unicode.

Comment: Not necesarilly, it might be used with "u" modifier in php as explained here http://cz.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php Anyway: this is not point of the question.