# Python password generator I’m trying to code isn’t working, but there’s no error message

Tags: python, passwords

I’m trying to make it work with regular expressions with user input, but it isn’t working, there is no error message. Maybe my if statement isn’t getting recognized?

````
print(“type password”)
password =input()

pattern=r”([0-10000000][a-z][A-Z])”

match=re.search(pattern,password)

if match and (len(password)<9) and (len(password)>4):
    print(“password is strong”)
else: 
    print(“password should have at least one letter, number, and capital letter included and be between 5 and 8 characters long”)```
````

Comment: What does _it isn’t working_ mean, exactly? Can you share some example input/output?

Comment: I don't think that regex does what you seem to think it does...

Comment: Your regex check returns `None` every time. You need to reevaluate your pattern. This will help ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029193/regex-for-at-least-8-upper-and-lowernumbers-or-other-non-alphabetic

Comment: @AMC whatever the input is, the output is always from the else statement, even when the input meets all of the criteria of the if statement.

Comment: @RobinZigmond can it not search through the input to see if it matches the criteria of the pattern?

Comment: _can it not search through the input to see if it matches the criteria of the pattern?_ Regex can do that, I think @PacketLoss's point was that yours isn't. I would recommend using something like https://regex101.com to examine your current regex, and build a new one.

Comment: @AMC Is there anything visibly wrong with my regex though? I can't get the string to match when I tried changing it on regex101.

Comment: _Is there anything visibly wrong with my regex though?_ I think so, yes. What is `[0-10000000]` meant to do?

Comment: Also, can you supply some examples of input?

Comment: @AMC It's meant to be any digit between 0 and 10000000, so that any password with 8 numbers can be validated. I'm not sure if \d works for that.

Comment: @AMC Things like... ghG789 that should meet the criteria.

Comment: @Kenna Be careful, a digit is a number between 0 and 9! You can check what `[0-10000000]` does on regex101. By the way, is the password restricted to numbers, lowercase numbers, and uppercase numbers?

Comment: @AMC It should be a mix of both lower and upper case letters and numbers, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through your current regex, `([0-10000000][a-z][A-Z])`:

1. `[0-10000000]` matches a single character in the range 0-1, or the character `0`.
2. `[a-z]` then matches a single character in the range a-z.
3. `[A-Z]` matches a single character in the range A-Z.

To put it all together: matches the number 0 or 1, followed by a lowercase letter, followed by an uppercase letter. That's quite different from what you intended.

---

The regex I came up with is this: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\da-zA-z]{5,8}$`. I [saved it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YYvNyN/1), so that you can easily see what it does, and test it.

Here is an example program:

```py
import re

pwd_patt = re.compile(r"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\da-zA-z]{5,8}$")

test_strs = ["Amc01", "Ac", "aa0aa", "aa0aaAadwaw", "ghG789"]

for curr_str in test_strs:
    print(curr_str, pwd_patt.fullmatch(curr_str))
```

Output:

```
Amc01 <re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='Amc01'>
Ac None
aa0aa None
aa0aaAadwaw None
ghG789 <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='ghG789'>
```

Comment: @Kenna Do you have any further questions?

Comment: yes, how would I loop the statement so that if the input is invalid, another password can be typed and checked again?

Comment: @Kenna Which part are you struggling with? I think that's another question entirely though.

Comment: Yeah it's another question, if you don't mind. The if statement only works one time, and I would like for the input to be typed more than one time, but on the second time any password is typed as input, it gives an error like '(whatever input) is not recognized'.

Answer (score -1):

u may try this version:

```
import re  # you probably missed the import 
print("type password")  # ALL quotes were of a different style! 
password =input()
pattern=r"([0-9]*)([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)"  # the regex was a little wrong try: regex101.com
match=re.search(pattern,password)
if match and 9 > len(password) > 4:  # changed also the condition to a more pythonic
    print("password is strong")
else:
    print("password is not between 5 and 8 characters long")
```

if you are new to python u may check also exercism it has nice exercises and you can have mentors that help!

Have fun with python it's great :-)

`import this`  # shows the Zen of python

Comment: Originally, the quotes were the same. Everyone seems to be suggesting regex101.com, but even on there I can't get the regex to match with a string. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: yes, there are shorter ones that do the same like: (([\w]*)([\d]*))+ or even quantified in braces to have the length check of the pw in the regex, but do we wan't to help or confuse... so step by step ;)