# Again some regex problems (password strength) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm again struggling with some regex syntax for a password validation.

The rules for a password are:

1. must contain at least number
2. must contain at least one special character of the set `. : , ; - $ % _ = ! ?`
3. must NOT contain other special characters than the set above in rule 2
4. may contain one or more regular word characters lowercase or uppercase

I've come so far:

```
var regex = /.*(?=.*[\.:,;\-\$%=\!\?])(?=.*\d).*/;
```

But this does only meet the rules 1 and 2 and allows any other special characters.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx expression to validate the input string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124796/regex-expression-to-validate-the-input-string)

Comment: did you search stackoverflow for an answer before asking your question? There are many questions nearly identical to the one you asked.

Comment: @Bryan: yes I did, but there was no appropriate solution. You linked article is not for JavaScript and didn't solve the "at least one special character" issue in combination with the other two rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> must contain at least number

```
/\d/
```

> must contain at least one special character of the set . : , ; - $ % _ = ! ?

```
/[.:,;\-$%_=!?]/
```

> must NOT contain other special characters than the set above in rule 2
>   may contain one or more regular word characters lowercase or uppercase

```
/^[a-z0-9.:,;\-$%_=!?]+$/
```

Putting it all together

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[a-z0-9]*[^a-z0-9])[a-z0-9.:,;\-$%_=!?]+$/i
```

And if you want to enforce a minimal length you can use `{6,}` or something similar,

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[a-z0-9]*[^a-z0-9])[a-z0-9.:,;\-$%_=!?]{6,}$/i
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Can you explain the whole regex in words (especially the beginning with the lookaheads?), I'd really like to understand what's going on.

Comment: The `^...$` means the pattern matches the entire string.  `\D*\d` means any number of non digits followed by a digit.  The punctuation stuff is handled by `[a-z0-9]*[^a-z0-9]` which means any number of alpha-numerics followed by a non-alpha-numeric.  Then the rest of it is an assertion that every character is a punctuation character you listed or an alpha numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be much more readable and understandable if you did **not** use regular expressions for this problem. Create one function for each rule (some of which can use regular expressions if you wish), then your check looks like:

```
if contains_digits(password) && \
   contains_special(password) && \
   only_contains_specific_chars(password) && \
   ...
```

Then it becomes trivial to add new rules or adjust existing rules. If you take a regular expression you don't understand, when the day comes when you have to modify it you will spend an entire day trying to figure it out.